# group array values by ID

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to combine arrays by the id and then sort by the date. The output array is:

```
    Array
(
    [abc] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 7
                    [date] => 2018-03-28
                    [message] => test1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 81
                    [date] => 2018-03-27
                    [message] => test5
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 7
                    [date] => 2018-03-27
                    [message] => test9
                )
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [date] => 2018-03-25
                    [message] => test
                )

        )

)
```

How do I show just the unique ID's sorted by date so that it displays:

```
id: 7 - 2018-03-28
id: 81 - 2018-03-27
id: 5 - 2018-03-25
```

Comment: you could loop through the current array to build a new one

Comment: Use `usort()` then do a `foreach` on the array result to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
<?php
$arr= array( 
    array( 'Id' => 7,
          'Date' => "2018-03-28", 
          'Message' => "test1" 
         ),
    array( 'Id' => 81,
          'Date' => "2018-03-27", 
          'Message' => "test2" 
         ),
    array( 'Id' => 7,
          'Date' => "2018-03-27", 
          'Message' => "test3" 
         ),
    array( 'Id' => 5,
          'Date' => "2018-03-25", 
          'Message' => "test4" 
         )
);

//Result array
$result = array();

// Check duplicate 'Id'
for($i=0;$i<(count($arr) -1);$i++)
{
    for($j=$i+1;$j<count($arr);$j++)
    {    
        if($arr[$j]['Id'] == $arr[$i]['Id'])
        {
            if($arr[$i]['Date'] >= $arr[$j]['Date'])
            {
                $arr[$j]['Date'] = $arr[$i]['Date'];
                $arr[$j]['Message'] = $arr[$i]['Message'];
            }
            else
            {
                $arr[$i]['Date'] = $arr[$j]['Date'];
                $arr[$i]['Message'] = $arr[$j]['Message'];
            }
        }
    }
}

// Remove value duplicate
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++)
{
    if(count($result) == 0)
    {
        array_push($result, $arr[$i]);
    }
    else
    {
        $flgAdd = true;
        foreach($result as $data){
            if($data['Id'] == $arr[$i]['Id']){
                $flgAdd = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if($flgAdd)
        {
            array_push($result, $arr[$i]);
        }
    }
}
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Hope it's ok

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way utilizing some PHP built-in functions for arrays as well as a user-defined function, as follows:

```
<?php
$arr= [ [ 'Id' => 7,
          'Date' => "2018-03-28",
          'Message' => "test1"
          ],
         [ 'Id' => 81,
         'Date' => "2018-03-27",
         'Message' => "test2" 
          ],
         ['Id' => 7,
          'Date' => "2018-03-27",
          'Message' => "test3" 
         ],
         ['Id' => 5,
          'Date' => "2018-03-25",
          'Message' => "test4" 
         ] ];

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['Date'] == $b['Date']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['Date'] < $b['Date']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($arr, 'cmp');

$dates = array_column($arr,'Date','Id');
arsort($dates);

foreach ($dates as $key => $value) {
        printf("id: %2d -  %s\n", $key, $value);
}
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/KVSf8#output)

My inclination was to apply array_multisort() to sort $arr.  But, then, I noted a drawback.  If the elements of each of the subarrays were ordered differently, then the results do not occur as expected; see [here](https://3v4l.org/oXZgj). One can deftly avoid that issue by using a customized sorting provided by [usort()](http://php.net/usort), passing in $arr to the function as well as the name of the user-defined function 'cmp' which performs a comparison of one element of $arr with the following, examining the value of the 'Date' fields.  Thereby, $arr gets sorted in ascending order by its 'Date' field.

Next, the array is passed to [array_column()](http://php.net/array_column), a function which first debuted in PHP 5.5 (you may view the internal C-source code in the *standard* extension's **array.c**). array_column() internally iterates over the array. Since the array is in ascending order by date value, those elements whose ids are the same will experience the one with the later date override the one one with the earlier date as the function extracts the "Date" and "Id" values from $arr.  Thereby, a new array forms whose values comprise the dates while the ids hold the 'Id' values.  The function [arsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) maintains the key association while doing a reverse sort of the date values, so they display in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

Without loop, Without conditions. You can achieve it by using some **array functions** and **sorting functions**.

```
$data = [ [ 'Id' => 7,
          'Date' => "2018-03-28",
          'Message' => "test1"
          ],
         [ 'Id' => 81,
         'Date' => "2018-03-27",
         'Message' => "test2" 
          ],
         ['Id' => 7,
          'Date' => "2018-03-27",
          'Message' => "test3" 
         ],
         ['Id' => 5,
          'Date' => "2018-03-25",
          'Message' => "test4" 
         ] ];
//Sorting recursively to get higher date.
array_multisort($data);
//Creating array Id as key Date as value. duplicate Id as key will be automatically overwriten.
$result = array_column($data, 'Date', 'Id');
//Sorting associative array in your desired output
arsort($result);
//Printing data
print_r($result);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [7] => 2018-03-28
    [81] => 2018-03-27
    [5] => 2018-03-25
)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/9b79U)